# PC stuck on GRUB screen WINDOWS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

Okay, so I had Ubuntu 20.04 installed alongside with Windows 10 on dual boot grub. Then I decoy to get rid of Ubuntu so from windows I deleted the Ubuntu partition and restarted my computer hoping I’d load into windows directly. After rebooting from windows, I got stuck on this grub screen instead of loading into windows. I’m working on a DELL Inspiron. I've tried booting into the DELL recovery and startup manager but it goes straight to this error on grub again.
The error: "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions." Also whenever I type into the grub thing I get random letters instead of the ones I press. PLEASE HELP ME!!

Also I’ve tried typing command ‘exit’ but that doesn’t work for me. I’ve tried other solutions and nothing works. I’m stuck and can’t load into windows In any way. Please please please help me!

Comment: When you deleted Ubuntu, you also deleted the information that GRUB needt to list and boot installed OS'es. You will have to boot into Windows, either by changing boot order in Bios (for UEFI) or by booting on Windows install media, and fix the boot information from there.

Comment: When I change the boot order, it goes to the same grub screen. What do it do now?

Comment: In @Melebius suggested dublicate, the first answer has a chapter called "Using Windows Recovery or Installation Media" follow that guide and recreate the Windows boot loader.

Comment: I checked that out but when I type in the command bootrec /fixmbr    I get an error saying: system cant find the file specified. What do I do now?